# Changing Mouse Wheel zoom direction in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, mouse-wheel

I'm just starting to learn QGIS. I'm starting with the basic simple things. Coming from an ArcGIS background, I am used to the mouse wheel action zooming in and out the default ArcGIS way. QGIS default is the opposite. The only option I seem to find about changing mouse action options is to enable or disable the mouse wheel action, but nothing about the altering the action.

Can I do this?

Comment: I can't stand how ArcGIS has the reverse zoom direction which is why I always change it when I log onto ArcGIS for the first time.  It's counter-intuitive and is opposite to how most other programs behave.  Sorry, I don't have an answer for you, just wanted to rant.

Comment: Ya, I was thinking that I'll just change ArcMap and get used to it that way. It's just years of working in that environment and it's hard to break habits! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible to change the direction.

In Options, you can change the zoom speed and behavior (zoom to mouse cursor, zoom, etc.) but not the general direction.

Comment: For reference, the relevant issue is here https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/30940

Answer (score 5):

It will be possible in QGIS 3.32 (see [this pull request](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/52303))

[image: zoom settings]

QGIS 3.32 will be released 2023-06-23 ([QGIS roadmap](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/roadmap.html#release-schedule))

Answer (score 2):

You can now change it with python in QGIS 3, unfortunately not in user interface yet (I am going to point out the issues with all this on QGIS github, meanwhile...)

Open python console - Plugins/Python console (Ctrl+Alt+p), and write there just this one line:

**iface.mapCanvas().setWheelFactor(0.5)**

This will revert the zoom in/ zoom out behavior. It is kind of saying change zoom to 50% (0.5) of current map zoom. Feel free to play with the number to get ideal behavior. Unfortunately you need to do that every time you open new map canvas this way, unless you link it automatically.

**Warning:** At this moment this changes not only wheel behavior but all zoom in / zoom out tools applied to that map canvas. So for example zoom in tool will work as zoom out when clicked on map canvas.